# How to pass data between UITableViewCells? ...and store the passed data?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, generics

[image][image]

What I am trying to achieve is illustrated in the image above: When `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` is called, I would like to pass data between it and another UITableViewController, the Input VC and DataVC. However I am stuck on how to achieve this.

There is a shared model for both of them, that allows updating cells when its underlying data changes.

I am planning to use the coordinator pattern for navigation between the UIViewControllers and *not* a Segue.

---

Here's the code I have come up with:

The model:

```swift
struct ModelForDealer {
   var dealerName: String?
}
```

Instance of the model in the UIViewController:

```swift
let modelForDealer: [ModelForDealer] = [
   ModelForDealer(dealerName: "General Motors"),
   ModelForDealer(dealerName: "General Motors"),
   ModelForDealer(dealerName: "General Motors"),
   ModelForDealer(dealerName: "General Motors"),
   ModelForDealer(dealerName: "General Motors"),
   ModelForDealer(dealerName: "General Motors")]
```

and cell-class in UIViewController:

```swift
class CellForDealer: UITableViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var titleForDealer: UILabel!
               
   func configCellForDealer(with model: ModelForDealer) {
      titleForDealer?.text = model.dealerName
   }
}
```

and in  `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt  indexPath: IndexPath)`

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   NSLog("Cell is tapped")
   switch indexPath.row {
   case 0:
    self.coordinator?.gotoDetailDataView()
   default:
     self.coordinator?.gotoDetailDataView()
     break
   }
}
```

Comment: provide a code what you tried

Comment: Add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Do you want to make the changes in `DetailVC` and reflect them in `InputVC`?

Comment: @PGDev, No, I would like the changes reflect back in InputVC where I tap the cell inside the InputVC which takes me to DetailVC, where I I tap the cell inside DetailVC, and the changes are reflected back in the InputVC. Is that possible..? then How, I am stuck..

Comment: @PGDev, I have updated the question details, can you have a look at it?

Comment: I've a question. If I tap on `cell-1` in `InputVC`, and then for every cell tap in `DetailVC` you want to reflect the data back in `cell-1` of `InputVC`? And what kind of updation you want to get reflected? Also, add the code where you're redirecting to `DetailVC`.

Comment: @PGDev, well, If i tap on cell-1 in InputVC it should go to cell - 1 in DetailVc, or If i tap cell-2 in InputVC, it should go to cell-2 in DetailVC, for example, in cell-1 in InputVC, lets say i have " Select your favorite color " and if i tap, it should show me cell-1 in detailVC with the list of colors, and then finally if i choose one of the colours, that chosen colour should be displayed back in InputVC.. i am stuck there..

Comment: @PGDev, do you see where i am going with this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216997/discussion-between-pgdev-and-letscode).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can proceed,

**1.** In your DetailVC create a handler and call it on didSelectRowAt and pass the relevant data in it

```
class DetailVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var handler: ((String)->())?
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let value = "Red Color" //get your data here that you want to pass back
        handler?(value)
    }
    
    //rest of the code...
}
```

**2.** Then set the handler when you're creating the instance of DetailVC in InputVC, i.e..

```
class InputVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    //rest of the code...
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.openDetailVC(model: modelForDealer[indexPath.row])
    }
    
    func openDetailVC(model: ModelForDealer) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailVC") as! DetailVC
        vc.handler = {(str) in //here....
            print(str)
        }
        //rest of the code...
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I got Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error, it says " Could not cast value of type InputVC to DetailVC"